# Reading-in a binary JPEG-Header (in Python)

Tags: python-3.x, jpeg, binaryfiles, binary-data

I would like to read in a JPEG-Header and analyze it.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure%20Wikipedia), the header consists of a sequences of markers. Each Marker starts with `FF xx`, where `xx` is a specific Marker-ID.

So my idea, was to simply read in the image in binary format, and seek for the corresponding character-combinations in the binary stream. This should enable me to split the header in the corresponding marker-fields.

For instance, this is, what I receive, when I read in the first 20 bytes of an image:

```
binary_data = open('picture.jpg','rb').read(20)
print(binary_data)
```

> b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1-\xfcExif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08'

My questions are now:

1) Why does python not return me nice chunks of 2 bytes (in hex-format).
Somthing like this I would expect:
`b'\xff \xd8 \xff \xe1 \x-' ... and so on`. Some blocks delimited by '\x' are much longer than 2 bytes.

2) Why are there symbols like `-, M, *` in the returned string? Those are no characters of a hex representation I expect from a byte string (only: 0-9, a-f, I think).

Both observations hinder me in writing a simple parser.
*So ultimately my question summarizes to: 
How do I properly read-in and parse a JPEG Header in Python?*

Comment: "Both observations hinder me in writing a simple parser." How does that do that, exactly? Are you aware that this is a *simplified* representation of binary data – because (obviously) your terminal cannot show 'actual' binary data? No other than the common notations `\n` and `\t`?

Comment: @usr2564301 But it could represent a byte in two 4 bit tuples; Like 1111 0000 is translated to F0, where every 4 bit are converted to the hex-number. M is not in that range.

Comment: Ummmm no. There is only one possible intepretation of the string `\xff`: **only** as a single byte. Every other interpretation would be shown different. But (again) why are you so worried about how it is represented on your screen? Please **do test** if the first character is a ``\`` and the second an `x` (as you seem to think), or, if it is the binary equivalent of `0xFF` followed by the binary equivalent of `0xD8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem overly worried about how your binary data is *represented on your console*. Don't worry about that.

The *default* built-in string-based representation that `print(..)` applies to a `bytes` object is just "printable ASCII characters as such (except a few exceptions), all others as an escaped hex sequence". The exceptions are semi-special characters such as `\`, `"`, and `'`, which could mess up the string representation. But this alternative representation does not change the values in any way!

```
>>> a = bytes([1,2,4,92,34,39])
>>> a
b'\x01\x02\x04\\"\''
>>> a[0]
1
```

See how the entire object is printed 'as if' it's a string, but its individual elements are still perfectly normal bytes?

If you have a byte array and you don't like the appearance of this default, then you can write your own. But – for clarity – this still doesn't have anything to do with *parsing* a file.

```
>>> binary_data = open('iaijiedc.jpg','rb').read(20)
>>> binary_data
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x02\x01\x00H\x00H\x00\x00'
>>> ''.join(['%02x%02x ' % (binary_data[2*i],binary_data[2*i+1]) for i in range(len(binary_data)>>1)])
'ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0201 0048 0048 0000 '
```

> Why does python not return me nice chunks of 2 bytes (in hex-format)?

Because you don't *ask* it to. You are asking for a sequence of `bytes`, and that's what you get. If you want chunks of two-bytes, transform it after reading.

The code above only prints the data; to create a new list that contains 2-byte words, loop over it and convert each 2 bytes or use [`unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) (there are actually several ways):

```
>>> wd = [unpack('>H', binary_data[x:x+2])[0] for x in range(0,len(binary_data),2)]
>>> wd
[65496, 65504, 16, 19014, 18758, 1, 513, 72, 72, 0]
>>> [hex(x) for x in wd]
['0xffd8', '0xffe0', '0x10', '0x4a46', '0x4946', '0x1', '0x201', '0x48', '0x48', '0x0']
```

I'm using the little-endian specifier `<` and unsigned short `H` in `unpack`, because (I assume) these are the conventional ways to represent JPEG 2-byte codes. Check the documentation if you want to derive from this.